# Syntax error in scheme

Tags: racket

I have a recursive function in Scheme that returns when I return it:
lambda: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 3 extra parts

What I am trying to do is to call this function with value in the list 'lst'.  This recursively gets all possible partitions in the list,

Comment: You're missing a level of parentheses in `cond`.

Comment: What is `(L)` supposed to mean? You have no function named `L`. And why do you have commas?

Comment: What is `(car L)`, there's no variable named `L` either. Should that be `lst`?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I meant to put lst

Comment: You still have a lot of invalid syntax. For example: `cdr(lst)`, `(+s1 ...)`, `(null ? ...)`, `(if (< a b) (a b)`.

Comment: @AlexanderMaru care to further explain? I'm not sure how any of those are invalid?

Comment: Sure. For example, `cdr(lst)` is invalid because `cdr` is a function, just like `car`, and you would use it the same way as any other function: `(function arguments...)`. So it becomes `(cdr lst)`. On the same note, `(+s1 ...)` is not the same as `(+ s1 ...)`. The former tries to apply a function called `+s1` (which in this case does not exist), while the latter applies the `+` procedure with s1 as its first argument. On the other hand, `if` should have three parts: condition expression, success expr, and failure expr. So it should be: `(if (< a b) a b)`. Also, `(null ? ...)` -> `(null? ...)`.

Comment: @AlexanderMaru thanks for the suggestions! I believe I have applied the suggestions and made the edits above, but I am still getting the same error message...sorry, but what else could possibly be wrong?

Comment: "what else could *possibly* be wrong?" -- how about, in `(define a(glcm (cdr(L) (+s1 (car L)) s2)))`, you use `L` as both a function and a list. *"On the same note, `(+s1 ...)` is not the same as `(+ s1 ...)`"* still applies.

Comment: The whole `cond` form is dead code since it is not the last expression. Since you don't have a base case that stops the recursion you will eventually do `cdr` and `car` on the empty list and it will fail.

Comment: @Sylwester right I understand someone else had mention the cond form.  Sorry, I have been looking up the porper way to make sure the cond form is correct, but I not exactly sure how.  Basically I wanted to say that if the list list null, return the lcm of the current two sums, if not then proceed to recursive function  which begin as 'define a'.  How exactly can I change my function to reflect this?

Answer (score 1):

A `define` must be the first expression in a lambda. Thus your `defien` are ill placed.

In addition you `cond` ended after the first term such that the rest of the code would be executed unconditionally and the `cond` being dead code as it did not change the outcome.

The closest correct syntax with minimal changes would be:

```
(define glcm
  (lambda (lst s1 s2)
    (cond
      [(null? lst) (lcm s1 s2)]
      [else
       (let ([a (glcm (cdr lst) (+ s1 (car lst)) s2)]
             [b (glcm (cdr lst) s1 (+ s2 (car lst)))])
         (if (< a b) a b))])))
```

Alternative, because `let` is a `lambda` call you can `define` inside a `let`:

```
(define glcm
  (lambda (lst s1 s2)
    (cond
      [(null? lst) (lcm s1 s2)]
      [else
       (let ()
         (define a (glcm (cdr lst) (+ s1 (car lst)) s2))
         (define b (glcm (cdr lst) s1 (+ s2 (car lst))))
         (if (< a b) a b))])))
```

However I would have done it like this:

```
(define (glcm lst s1 s2)
  (if (null? lst)
      (lcm s1 s2)
      (min (glcm (cdr lst) (+ s1 (car lst)) s2)
           (glcm (cdr lst) s1 (+ s2 (car lst))))))
```

They most likely become very similar object code. Use whatever you think is most readable for you.

Notice I use `[...]`. These are really indistinguishable with `(...)` so it's only a visual queue to make it more readable. Before R5RS you'd have to only use `(...)` to be compatible. DrRacket IDE even rewrites the ending parenthesis to match the type of the matching beginning parenthesis.